# CLLocationManager zoom in-zoom out

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I have implemented a `CLLocationManager` to show user location. Once a user clicks a button, the map zooms in the user location. However, once the user would like to zoom out back, it does not allow user to zoom out. Actually, it zooms out a little bit, but again it zooms in!!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use CLLocationManager to get the user location when you have a map view. You can use the map view's userLocation property, and you can also listen to the delegate callback that will give you updates about the user location.

Since you are not presenting any code, I would say that either on the MKMapView delegate method or the CLLocationManager delegate method, you are zooming in and/or focusing on the newest location. Since this is a delegate method being updated as soon as there is a new location, you might be zooming in every time. If you only want to zoom in once, you might want to try dispatching a dispatch_once block to make sure that you are only zooming in the first time there is a coordinate update. You can also modify the CLLocationManager so it only updates the location when there has been a significant distance change by using the distance filter property. It all depends on what you are trying to accomplish.